# SQL INNER JOIN without linked column

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have an UltraGrid displaying customer information in it. The way the database is set up, there are 2 tables. `Customers` and `Customer_Addresses`. I need to be able to display all of the columns from `Customers` as well as `Town` and `Region` from `Customer_Addresses`, but I'm under the impression that I'd need Town and Region columns in the `Customer` table to be able to do this? I've never used an `INNER JOIN` before so I'm not sure if this is true or not, so can anybody give me pointers on how to do this, or if I need the matching columns or not?

Does it even require an `INNER JOIN`, or is there an alternative way to do this?

Below are the design views of both of the tables - Is it possible to display `Add4` and `Add5` from `Customer_Addresses` with all of `Customers`?

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate the question and share sample input/output?

Comment: Perhaps you can post the table schemas for Customer and Customer_Address.  There is likely a AddressId or CustomerId that relates the 2 tables together for use in an inner join so you can query the tables together.  I am not sure I understood your comment of Town and Region being on the Customer but that seems like an incorrect impression

Comment: if you have never used an inner join before, your sql knowledge is very low.  Learning some basics is a good investment of time and effort.  I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in Ten Minutes.

Comment: @Matt Hi, both design views of that tables are above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have another *key column* you can use to link the tables (ex. ID_Column), it is better that you use LEFT JOIN.

Example:

```
SELECT c.col1, ... , c.colN, a.town, a.region FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Customer_Addresses a ON a.ID_Column = c.ID_Column
```

In order to clarify how JOIN types work, look at this picture:
[image]

In our case, using a LEFT JOIN will take **all** information from the Customers table, along with any found **matching** (on ID) information from Customer_Addresses table.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly - `SELECT (c.all columns), {a.Town], [a.Region] FROM [Customers] c LEFT JOIN [Customer_Addresses] a ON a.Cust_Code = c.Customer_Code`?

Comment: @joe That looks perfect (without the `{` typo).. As long as `Cust_Code` and `Customer_Code` are equal and unique in their tables

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need some column in common in two tables, all what you have to do is:

```
CREATE TABLE all_things 
AS 
   SELECT * (or columns that you want to have in the new table) 
   FROM Costumers AS a1  
   INNER JOIN Customer_Addresses AS a2 ON a1.column_in_common = a2.column_in_common
```

The point is what kind of join do you want.

If you can continue the process without having information in table Costumers or in table Customer_Addresses maybe you need OUTER JOIN or other kind of JOIN.

Comment: I tried with this code, and it gave me the error of "Error in CREATE TABLE query"

`sql = "CREATE TABLE Customer_List AS SELECT {Customers.Customer_Code}, {Customers.Customer_Name}, {Customers.Telephone}, {Customers.Email}, {Customers.salesRep} FROM Customers As a1 LEFT JOIN Customer_Addresses AS a2 On a1.Customer_Code = a2.Cust_Code"`